# How to call a promise on Firebase's ''on'' method?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6, promise

I have a
 `databaseReference.on("child_added", snap => { array.push(snap.val()) }`

How do I make a promise, so that any function I call in `.then` will be initialized AFTER `array` is filled with database records?

The code above is essentially a `for` loop, because it iterates through database records and pushes each one of them into an array, so maybe better question would be how to implement a promise on a `for` loop ?

The best I've found was to return promise with each iteration and then use `Promise.all`, but I have no clue on how to implement that in this specific example.

Comment: how do you know when `child_added` "loop" is "done"? is there some other event to notify you of that? without knowing when it is "done", a promise wont help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[on()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) doesn't generate a promise.  And it can't, because the listener you pass to it lasts forever (and continues to deliver changes) until it's removed with [off()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#off).  This behavior is not compatible with promises.  Promises require that some work is executed only once, and once that completes, nothing else should occur that would change the result.

If you want to receive data for a single snapshot at a location, use [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) instead of on().  once() returns a promise that's resolved when the data is available.  This is fundamentally not compatible with 'child_added' listeners, as they always continually generate results and never terminate with a final result.

Comment: That is a great clarification. Thank you!